# Problema para desplegar elementos de JSON en HTML (Python, Django framework)

Tags: python, django

Quisiera saber si alguien podría ayudarme con una aplicación en flask que lee una api que devuelve un json con extensiones de dominios y precios. El problema lo tengo en que la tabla HTML despliega el primer elemento (extension del dominio) pero los precios no los despliega, me da un valor indeterminado.
Se que el error lo tengo en llamar los elementos que pertenecen a la extensión, y no he podido resolverlo.

El código en python es:

```
@app.route('/', methods=("POST", "GET"))
```

def to_json():
url = 'https://porkbun.com/api/json/v3/pricing/get'

```
headers = {
     'apikey': '',
    'secretapikey': '',
}

session = Session()
session.headers.update(headers)
response = session.get(url)
data = response.json()
return render_template('dataset.html', dominios=data)
```

if **name** == '**main**':
app.run(debug=True)

y el HTML es :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

{%if dominios %}
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
                <tr style="text-align: left;">
                    
                <th>Dominio</th>
                    <th>Registro</th>
                <th>Renovación</th>
                <th>Transferencia</th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                {%for dom in dominios['pricing']%}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ dom }}</td>
                    <td>{{ [dom['registration']] }}</td>
            <td>{{ [dom['renewal']] }}</td>
            <td>{{ [dom['transfer']] }}</td>
                </tr>
                {%endfor%}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    {%endif%}
</body>
</html>
```

La respuesta en el explorador es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta, bastante sencilla y el mismo framework me la indicó. Para iterar los items se debe usar la forma "x" y "y" para clave y valor. Así el código final es;

```
                            {% for dominio, precios in dominios.pricing.items  %}
                                <td>{{ dominio }}</td>
                                <td>{{ precios.registration }}</td>
                                <td>{{ precios.renewal }}</td>
                                <td>{{ precios.transfer }}</td>
                                <td>{{ precios.coupons.code }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}    
                        </tbody>
```